# dateTimePicker C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Кто знает как получить системные дату и время ? Компонент dateTimePicker поможет? Если да, как выдернуть из него дату и время к примеру в Label?

А может быть у кого-нибудь есть исходник автозапуска программы в заданное в ней время? Обязательно на C++ Builder

Answer (score 1):

```
// Вывод даты-времени на лейбл
Label1->Caption = Now();
```

По поводу второй части идея такая: программа запускается при старте системы в скрытом виде. На форме лежит таймер срабатывющий например каждую минуту и проверяющий не совпадает ли время с заданным. Если время совпадает, то форму нужно показать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
DateTimePicker1->Date=(Date());
sLabelFX1->Caption=TimeToStr(Now())+" ";
sLabelFX2->Caption=DateToStr(DateTimePicker1->Date);
```